# jQuery .animate({ 'width' : 'show' }) doesn't work properly in Chrome/Safari?

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, safari, webkit, jquery-animate

This piece of code works in Firefox and IE:

```
$('input').click(function() {       
    $(group).animate({
        'width' : 'show'
    }, 2000, "easeInOutCirc");

});
```

However, in webkit browsers (Chrome and Safari), it doesn't. But if I use `$(group).show();`, it works in all browsers.

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to my question. For some reason, I needed to set the css property in jQuery instead of just hiding `$(group)` via `.hide()`. So what I did was to put this line of code at the beginning:

```
$(group).css("display","none");
```

instead of

```
$(group).hide();
```

Now it works. Anyway, thanks for the input!

Answer (score 1):

please change this

```
'width' : 'show'
```

to

```
'width' :  'toggle'
```

or use

```
"opacity": "show"
```

Comment: 'width' : 'toggle' doesn't work. I can use 'opacity' : 'show' but it doesn't have the same effect that I need when I use width. :|

Comment: sorry opacity should be 1 not 0 `.animate({width: "show", opacity: 1})`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3125/discussion-between-chamika-sandamal-and-catandmouse)